# Web2py on App Engine Local Environment: Cannot access admin interface

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I have been trying to learn web2py for use on App Engine. However I cannot seem to be able to access the admin interface.
(The default page loads, when I access it from 127.0.0.1:8080. To access the admin interface, the url used should be 127.0.0.1 (by default))
[image: homepage of web2py]

However when I click the admin interface link all I get is this page
[image: error admin page web2py on local gae]

Logging in with any email id does not work.

I have been through the tutorial at http://wiki.web2py.com/Deploying_web2py_on_Google_App_Engine_GAE_ however, it does not talk about setting a password to access the admin interface on the local App Engine environment.(And I think it is out of date)

I have also been through the [web2py book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/03) which talks about setting up a password to access the admin environment (when using the web2py server, this chapter does not talk about app engine)

**Questions:**
Do I have to set a password to access the admin interface while it is deployed on the local app engine server? If yes, how?
If not, How do I access the admin interface?
Finally, Can I access the admin interface when the app is deployed on the remote GAE servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set an admin password during the installation process.
Check this [video](http://www.vimeo.com/932708) at 00:35 or read [this](http://www.web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/104) doc.

Comment: I can access it now. That means that even though I do not want to use the web2py server, I need to run it once to set the password. Then I can turn it off and use the same password to access the admin console while running web2py on the local GAE SDK server

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to access the admin interface when the app is deployed on the remote GAE servers because admin requires access to a filesystem, and GAE doesn't allow writing to the filesystem. So, you'll be limited to local usage.